# PowerBI RLS on slicer in dashboard

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers, row-level-security

[image]

Hello everyone,

The screenshot above is my data model for PowerBI dashboard. I already set the "Cross filter direction" between City lookup and Restaurant Inspection Data to "Both".

I applied RLS on the Inspector Lookup table as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I tried to test the RLS by using "View as" in PowerBI, most of the DAX measures and visuals work well. However, I realized that the filter from RLS did not apply on the City Lookup table even thought I already set the cross filter direction to "Both". Below are the 2 screenshots before I applied RLS and after I applied RLS:

### Before applying RLS:

[image]

### After applying RLS:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, after I applied the RLS, the bar chart and column chart at the left hand side were filtered but City slicer and table at the right hand side still remain the same. What I need to do is select the Inspector Name in the slicer, then the table and city slicer only reflected accordingly as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

May I know is there any way that I can avoid this situation? By right, if I want to apply RLS, there is no Inspector Name slicer in my dashboard since each inspector is only able to see his own data so the inspector slicer is useless to put in the dashboard. I want the City table are able to affected by the RLS as well, any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default RLS filters do not traverse backwards even when a relationship is configured for bidirectional cross-filtering.

If you want that you simply set the "Apply security filter in both directions" option on the bidirectional cross-filtering relationship.

[image]

But it's not a best-practice to use bi-directional relationships to filter slicers. As Alberto Ferrari, an absolute authority, says:

> Implementing bidirectional cross-filter for the purpose of syncing
> slicers is definitely a bad idea. After all, if you need to kill ants
> in the yard, you do not turn on the Death Star.

[Bidirectinoal relationships and ambiguity in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/bidirectional-relationships-and-ambiguity-in-dax/)

One alternative is use a visual-level filter on the slicer instead:
[Filter Slicers Without using Bi-directional relationships](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/syncing-slicers-in-power-bi/)

If you really need to secure the city dimension, use a separate security table.  This can be derived from your fact table, eg

```
CitySecurity = DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(NATURALINNERJOIN(Inspector,Data),"CityId",[CityId],"Email", [Email]))
```

Set RLS on that table and configure it to apply security filters to the City table though a bidirectional relationship, which is the normal RLS security pattern for dimension tables.

[image]

Comment: Thanks David, this work for me! But I realized that "Apply security filter in both directions" only allowed for once. If I have another slicer for product lookup table (new table), I'm not allowed to use the same method anymore. It mentioned that only one relationship per table with this setting is allowed. Is there anyway that I could do?

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Do you mean that I need to create another security table for product lookup table if I want the slicer for product to behave the same? If I create multiple RLS for multiple dimension table, will all these RLS work together?

Comment: You can secure as many dimensions as you need to.